# Built a query for polygon Shapefile in R

Tags: shapefile, r, query

I use the package `maptools` to read in Shapefiles in R. I would like to know if there is a function that can built up a query/subset to select only some Polygons based on a specific attribute in the a.t. (for example one state out of a shapefile with all states in one country). And, can I save this subset as a spatial object to do further analyses in R?
Best

Comment: Comment: don't use maptools for reading, use readOGR from package:rgdal - it will preserve any coordinate reference info from the shape file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarize the very useful comments by @Spacedman, @JeffreyEvans and @AriB.Friedman, but also to address the questioner's second problem about saving the generated subset and to provide a reproducible example for future audience, let me add a brief example to cover the whole topic. In fact, I'm much more often working with raster data than point or polygon shapefiles, so this was also pretty useful for me.

As @Spacedman mentioned, you should rather use `rgdal` instead of `maptools` for the given reason.

```
library(rgdal)
```

Now, let's download a [suitable ESRI shapefile](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f7f805eb65eb4ab787a0a3e1116ca7e5) containing all states of the US and extract it to a folder named 'data' in your current working directory. After that, you are ready to import the shapefile using `readOGR()`.

```
usa.states <- readOGR(dsn = "data", layer = "states")
```

You can now create a subset of this SpatialPolygonsDataFrame either via accessing the `@data` slot (thanks @JeffreyEvans, I didn't know that...) or addressing a particular column solely via the `$` operator. Let's take New York for our testing purposes:

```
newyork <- usa.states[usa.states$STATE_NAME == "New York", ]
# Or alternatively... :-)
newyork <- usa.states[usa.states@data$STATE_NAME == "New York", ]
```

Have a look at the generated subset via `plot(newyork)`. Now that you know that everything worked, use `writeOGR()` to save the shapefile to the desired folder ('data' in our case). If you're not sure whether 'ESRI Shapefile' or any other driver is available on your local system, check `ogrDrivers()` prior to sending the `writeOGR()` statement to the console.

```
writeOGR(oregon, dsn = "data", layer = "oregon", 
         driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
```

That's it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

ok this was easier than i thought: `spatial.subset<-states.shp[5,]` if you know which line in your attribute table should be the subset. If you don't know you could do something like `spatial.subset<-states.shp[states.shp@data$STATE=="California" ,]` for a single state or  `spatial.subset<-states.shp[c(states.shp@data$POPULATION>1000000),]` for several states with a population greater than 1.Mio.

Comment: This doesn't look like it's an attribute query.  Perhaps you could elaborate on how it answers your question?

Comment: @whuber you are right. Please note the edits in the answer to make it more comprehensive.

Comment: Using "which" could have unexpected behavior and is quite unnecessary. You should also be accessing the data slot in the bracket index. This will get you what you want.  states.shp[states.shp@data$STATE=="California" ,]

Comment: @JeffreyEvans all right. I edited it in the answer

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Why is accessing the `@data` slot necessary?  `$` is overloaded for `Spatial*DataFrame` objects to return the named column of the `@data` slot, and thus reaching inside the object's structure would seem to be disfavored over using the appropriate method....

Comment: Because calling the slot is much more version proof. Until very recently you could not call a column in the data slot without explicitly accessing the slot object.